# user should be prompt for new version upgrade and download whenever same is updated on server

Tags: java, swt

i have a java application which is running on client machine that tool need to have version info and user should  be prompt  for new version upgrade and download whenever same is updated  on server.

Comment: That's not the kind of questions we like to answer on SO. It's actually not a question at all. Attempt something and tell us what didn't work and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain version in client executable as constant. e.g X.Y.Z

On start of application this constant (X.Y.Z) should be checked against latest version number stored on centralize server(in a database table or flatfile or can use webservice)

if version doesn't match you can launch browser with URL where latest executable are available. You can automatically kick the download as well.